# View passing wrong viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created a website using ASP.Net MVC5 (VS 2013) but I guess the same problem would present itself in MVC3 or MVC4

I have the following view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WilhanWebsite.Models.TestimonialViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Testimonial.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Testimonial.Author)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Testimonial.Timestamp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Testimonial.TestimonialId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Testimonial.TestimonialId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Testimonial.TestimonialId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The Index action of my Testimonial controller sends back a List and the view displays existing testimonials correctly in the html table. My problem is that when I click the Edit hyperlink I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'WilhanWebsite.DomainClasses.Testimonial', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'WilhanWebsite.Models.TestimonialViewModel'

I was previously using DomainClasses.Testimonial as the model passed between controller an view but today I refactored to create the new dedicated view model. It seems strange that the view is happy to process the new viewmodel when displaying the data so why is it passing the old DomainClasses.Testimonial when I click the Edit link?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your edit action and view look like (code)?

Comment: Either your edit action is sending the wrong model type or your view is coded to accept the wrong model type.  This has nothing to do with your index view.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks both for your reply. You were both right - the problem was with the Edit action of my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix by updating the Edit action to the following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var query = from t in _context.Testimonials
                    where t.TestimonialId == id
                    select t;

        TestimonialViewModel tvm = new TestimonialViewModel();
        tvm.Testimonial = query.First();
        return View(tvm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The View expects `@model IEnumerable<WilhanWebsite.Models.TestimonialViewModel>` so you have to **return** it from the Controller's Index action method. Without seeing your controller I would guess that your returning a **List** of type **Testimonial** rather than a **List** of Type **TestimonialViewModel**

// GET: /Testimonial/

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<TestimonialViewModel> testimonialViewModel = new  List<TestimonialViewModel>();
    // Add some testimonials to your list. 
    return View(testimonialViewModel);

    //NOT THIS - IT WILL THROW THE ERROR YOUR GETTING
    return View(db.Testimonial.ToList());
}
```

//Testimonial/Index

```
@model IEnumerable<WilhanWebsite.Models.TestimonialViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
```

---

Alternativly if you are returning a System.Collection and **TestimonialViewModel** is specified. Make sure that its implements IEnumerable. The following types do.

ICollection
IDictionary
IDictionaryEnumerator
IEnumerable
IEnumerator
IHashCodeProvider
IList

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was with the Edit action. I was focused on the Index action and so didn't provide enough information in the question.

Comment: You're welcome. That error message is the worst description of an error... in MVC. Rather than dictionary they could use Data Dictionary or View but dictionary doesn't really say much.